# GuzzleHttp Parallel Progress For Async Client in Azure and Flysystem

Tags: azure, guzzle, progress, transfer, flysystem

I would like to get the actual block progress and not the Progress of all the transfers. Currently i don't know how to detect the blockId of each individual transfer. The information on the progress callback im currently retrieving is pointless.

Here's the progress function, contained within ServiceRestProxy.php

Original Function https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-common/src/Common/Internal/ServiceRestProxy.php#L99

```
/**
 * Create a Guzzle client for future usage.
 *
 * @param  array $options Optional parameters for the client.
 *
 * @return Client
 */
private static function createClient(array $options)
{
    $verify = true;
    //Disable SSL if proxy has been set, and set the proxy in the client.
    $proxy = getenv('HTTP_PROXY');
    // For testing with Fiddler
    // $proxy = 'localhost:8888';
    // $verify = false;
    if (!empty($proxy)) {
        $options['proxy'] = $proxy;
    }

    if (!empty($options['verify'])) {
        $verify = $options['verify'];
    }

    $downloadTotal = 0;

    return (new \GuzzleHttp\Client(
        array_merge(
            $options,
            array(
                "defaults" => array(
                    "allow_redirects" => true,
                    "exceptions" => true,
                    "decode_content" => true,
                ),
                'cookies' => true,
                'verify' => $verify,
                'progress' => function (
                    $downloadTotal,
                    $downloadedBytes,
                    $uploadTotal,
                    $uploadedBytes
                ){
                    // i need to detect which block the progress is for.
                    echo ("progress: download: {$downloadedBytes}/{$downloadTotal}, upload: {$uploadedBytes}/{$uploadTotal}");
                }
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to get each block progress.

I needed to use the Async Function for this. Updated version.

```
/**
 * Send the requests concurrently. Number of concurrency can be modified
 * by inserting a new key/value pair with the key 'number_of_concurrency'
 * into the $requestOptions of $serviceOptions. Return only the promise.
 *
 * @param  callable       $generator   the generator function to generate
 *                                     request upon fulfillment
 * @param  int            $statusCode  The expected status code for each of the
 *                                     request generated by generator.
 * @param  ServiceOptions $options     The service options for the concurrent
 *                                     requests.
 *
 * @return \GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise|\GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromiseInterface
 */
protected function sendConcurrentAsync(
    callable $generator,
    $statusCode,
    ServiceOptions $options
) {
    $client = $this->client;
    $middlewareStack = $this->createMiddlewareStack($options);

    $progress = [];

    $sendAsync = function ($request, $options) use ($client, $progress) {
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'HEAD') {
            $options['decode_content'] = false;
        }

        $options["progress"] = function(
                $downloadTotal,
                $downloadedBytes,
                $uploadTotal,
                $uploadedBytes) use($request, $progress){
            // extract blockid from url
            $url = $request->getUri()->getQuery();
            parse_str($url, $array);

            // this array can be written to file or session etc
            $progress[$array["blockid"]] = ["download_total" => $downloadTotal, "downloaded_bytes" => $downloadedBytes, "upload_total" => $uploadTotal, "uploaded_bytes" => $uploadedBytes];

            };
        return $client->sendAsync($request, $options);
    };

    $handler = $middlewareStack->apply($sendAsync);

    $requestOptions = $this->generateRequestOptions($options, $handler);

    $promises = \call_user_func(
        function () use (
            $generator,
            $handler,
            $requestOptions
        ) {
            while (is_callable($generator) && ($request = $generator())) {
                yield \call_user_func($handler, $request, $requestOptions);
            }
        }
    );

    $eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises, [
        'concurrency' => $options->getNumberOfConcurrency(),
        'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) use ($statusCode) {
            //the promise is fulfilled, evaluate the response
            self::throwIfError(
                $response,
                $statusCode
            );
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
            //Still rejected even if the retry logic has been applied.
            //Throwing exception.
            throw $reason;
        }
    ]);

    return $eachPromise->promise();
}
```